# Angular 4 in *ngFor to calculate sum of total value

Tags: angular

I'm making a little application in Angular 4, 
i want to display sum of total value when iterating through *ngfor.

HTML CODE

```
<ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes;">
    <li>{{hero.name}}  <span>{{hero.price*hero.qty}}</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li>Total <span>{{total}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

COMPONENT

```
 total:number;
 heroes: Hero[];
 ngOnInit():void 
 {
 this.heroService.getnewHeroes()
 .then(heroes => {this.heroes = heroes});
 }
```

SERVICE

```
 getnewHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> 
  {
     return this.http.get('api/heroes').toPromise()
     .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
  }
```

I want output like below

abc 500*2

xyz 200*5

---

Total 2000

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Calculate your total in the `Component` and assign it to a new property. Do not try to do the sum calculation inside the `ngFor` loop, that is not what it was designed for.
- Displaying the total outside the `ngFor`.
- Also you use `*ngFor` on the element you want to repeat, `li` in this case. If you put it on `ul` then you will create a new unordered list for every hero instead of a new list item *inside* then unordered list tag.

Component code:

```
heroes: Hero[];
total: number;
ngAfterContentChecked()  {
    this.total = this.heroes.reduce(funtion(runningValue: number, hero: Hero)=> {
      runningValue = runningValue + (hero.price * hero.qty);
    }, 0);
}
```

Template code:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}} <span>{{hero.price*hero.qty}}</span></li>
  <li>Total price <span>{{total}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @VaradhaRaj - I do not know what `previousValue` is, it is not in the code you have shown in your question and it is not in the code I have written to fix your problems that you had in the question. You will have to update your question with the *complete* code that you are now using that is causing the error.

Comment: the above code working fine, after made very few changes. thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Igor , maybe you can help me in my question...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388155/how-do-i-obtain-the-value-of-an-object-that-will-be-used-to-calculate-operations