# How do I obtain the value of an object that will be used to calculate operations?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get every object in my `data` matrix, because at that moment it is completely printing the value of my`data` and I just need to obtain an object (`calculo_impuesto, cantidad_factura_pivote, costo_factura_pivote`) from `data[obj]`:

So, at this point I'm doing a service (which gets the values of `data` and therefore from my constructor I make the respective request to obtain them and later be used in my component), so`this.calculateData (data) ;`is just a 'pivot' call to the function where I want to perform the addition or multiplication calculations.

---

**SERVICE**

```
  public getProductInvoice()
  {
    return new Promise(
      resolve=>{
        this.http.get('authentication/consultarProductoFactura.php')
        .subscribe(
        data => resolve(data)
        )
      }
    )
  };
```

**COMPONENT**

```
  refreshData()
  {
    this._serviceInvoice.getProductInvoice()
    .then(data=>{
      this.listProduct= data;
      this.getProductInvoice();
      this.calculateData(data);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  calculateData(data)
  {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(obj =>
    {
       //Here I need to get the values of my data, this as example, I don't really know how do or get it?
       console.log(data[obj.costo_factura_pivote])
       console.log(data[obj.cantidad_factura_pivote])

       //After having the values of data I need to do this:
       subtotal += costo_factura_pivote *  cantidad_factura_pivote;
    });
  };
```

---

**OBJECT**

```
  Object 
  { 
    calculo_impuesto: "1.19"
​    cantidad_factura_pivote: "2"
​    cantidad_minima_producto: "5"
​    codigo_producto: "COD002"
​    costo_factura_pivote: "430000"
​    costo_venta_producto: "430000"
​    descuento_factura_pivote: "0"
​    fecha_factura_pivote: "2018-09-14"
​    id_empresa_factura_pivote: "1"
​    id_factura_pivote: "1"
​    id_impuesto: "4"
​    id_impuesto_producto: "4"
​    id_producto: "2"
​    nombre_impuesto: "IVA"
​    nombre_producto: "Dymo 450"
​    valor_impuesto: "19"
 }
```

**CONSOLE DATA (IN SPANISH)**

[image: Log Image]

**Why I need this?**

Because, I need to get the subtotal, calculate the taxes, and the discount of my invoice. In this case are 3 items of that invoice, maybe can be more. So, having that how can calculate a sum (costs) of that objects, for example from: (costo_factura_pivote)?

I'm trying to get the subtotal of each object obtained from my service, for example: I have twp products, product A (cost 10 USD) (quantity: 20 unities), product B (cost 15 USD) (quantity: 10 unities), so, I need to sum both value:

Product A = 10 USD * 20 unities >  200 USD

Product B = 15 USD * 10 unities > 150 USD

```
(costo_factura_pivote *  cantidad_factura_pivote)
```

**Subtotal (A,B) = 350 USD**

Comment: Btw You can do just `this.http.get('authentication/consultarProductoFactura.php').toPromise()` instead of this harakiri :] (you might need to import `toPromise` operator depending on your rxjs version.

Comment: Please translate "obtenerProductoFactura" in the function "getProductInvoice" you call in the component, it will be more readable :)

Comment: Yes, I did it, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you just need to do `data[obj].costo_factura_pivote` instead of `data[obj.costo_factura_pivote]`?  If that isn't it, please add the entire `console.log(data)` to the question.  (In the console screenshot, you have two log entries each with one product, but I would expect a single log entry with an object containing multiple products.)