# sum elements of my collection with forEach

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting a little problem when I'm trying to sum a little objects or elements from my collection, but in this way it is as if the data obtained were concatenated as strings of type string and the result it's:

```
Total:  05500000005
```

And the expected result it's:

```
Total:  15
```

This is my code `forEach` to go through the elements of my collection:

```
let total = 0;

data.forEach(element => {
  console.log("Element: ", element.cost_product);
  total += element.cost_product;
});
console.log("Total: ", total)
```

Comment: Try changing `element.cost_product` to `+element.cost_product` to convert it from a string to a number. However depending on what element is this may be a hack that would obscure the underlying issue - if element is an object you control, you should probably be ensuring it has a numerical value sooner.

Comment: I did a question of my real problem, but in this case I've done a little advance with the solution, so, for that I've decided to make this new question. I've found the way to get an element of my collection, but with your `+element.cost_product` solved my problem, but like you said "this may be a hack that would obscure the underlying issue ", what can I do?  [Last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388155/how-do-i-obtain-the-value-of-an-object-that-will-be-used-to-calculate-operations?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```
const total = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(total); // 6
```

In your case it's more convenient to do like this.

```
const total = [{cost_product: 1}, {cost_product: 2}, {cost_product: 5}].reduce(function (acc, obj) { return acc + obj.cost_product; }, 0);
console.log(total);
```

ES6

```
const total = [{ cost_product: 1 }, { cost_product: 2 }, { cost_product: 5 }].reduce((
    acc,
    obj,
  ) => acc + obj.cost_product,
  0);

console.log(total);
```

If cost_product is string you can try this

```
const total = [{ cost_product: "1" }, { cost_product: "2" }, { cost_product: "5" }].reduce((
    acc,
    obj,
  ) => acc + Number(obj.cost_product),
  0);

console.log(total);
```

With condition

```
  const total = [{ cost_product: 1 }, { cost_product: 2 }, { cost_product: 5 }].reduce((
    acc,
    obj,
  ) => {
    if (obj.cost_product >= 1 && obj.cost_product <= 4) {
      return acc + Number(obj.cost_product);
    }

    return acc;
  },
  0);

  console.log(total);
```

Comment: Or in op's case, more like `data.map(el => el.cost_product).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: The `+` operator does both string concatenation and addition. If you want the latter, you need to cast the strings to numbers.

Comment: Can you explain why you use the `acc`?

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters): 

> The accumulator accumulates the callback's return values; it is the accumulated value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback, or initialValue, if supplied (see below).

In fact, instead of defining the global variable, we define the internal `total` variable. 
I hope I didn't say anything wrong.

Comment: Great, the fourth solution has solved my problem! and I can sum or multiply values, why didnt you show up before? haha

Comment: Hi @ccoeder, if I want to do a condition inside, how can I do it? for example, if I only want to take the values that have a cost between 10 and 50 and that those can add them up and the others obviate them or do not take them into account

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code as followed:

```js
let data = [{cost_product: 5},{cost_product: 1}]

let total = 0;

data.forEach(element => {
  console.log("Element: ", element.cost_product);
  total += element.cost_product;
});
console.log("Total: ", total)
```

And it works just fine. Check your cost_product type if it's really a number and not a string.

Comment: The data that I'm calling its from a service (GET), and the `data` its the `.then` from service response. Maybe, do you know how set up that as number, because in my DB are declared as INT value

Comment: Change `console.log("Element: ", element.cost_product);` to `console.log("Element: ", typeof element.cost_product, element.cost_product);` to see the type of each element's `cost_product` attribute. I expect if you change the line `total += element.cost_product;` to `total += +element.cost_product;` (call the unary `+` operator on the value before adding it to the total to force it to a number) your code will work.

Comment: Yes, it works but I need to know whats happening for that, may can be my service data ?

Comment: ...And if I put the operator `+` its a `number` type, if not I use it, the type of that value its `string`, as expected!

Comment: There you go then. Somewhere along the way you're storing the data as a string and not a number.

Edit: Just took a look at your last question post. Your data is definitely stored as strings and your DB is interpreting them as numbers when its entirely composed of numbers.